# Problem regarding open systems and a compression

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, phase-transition, volume

Say we have a cylinder of height $h_0$ and transversal area $S_\perp$ filled with water vapour and covered by diathermic walls, as well as a mobile diathermic piston on the top, which is in contact with a very big container which is at a temperature of $T_0$ and a pressure of $P_0$. Imagine we now place weights on top of the piston, and as soon as some water liquid appears, we stop putting weights. How we can try and find those masses?

I thought to try and start with the Clapeyron-Clausius, knowing that we know the $\Delta H_{vaporization}$ of the water and the molar mass $M$, we have that $$\frac{dp}{dT}=\frac{\Delta h}{T\Delta v}$$ being $p,v$ the molar volumes and molar pressures. I think we can also use the approximation in $\Delta v=v_{liquid}-v_{gas}\approx -v_{gas}$ but I'm pretty lost from here, since we don't know the final pressures or final temperatures either.

Comment: Is the water vapor saturated in the initial condition?

Comment: @ChetMiller I don't know what you mean by saturated (I'm not native), in the initial condition, the only thing I know is that there is water in the vapour state inside the cylinder and after the compression, the first drop of water liquid appears.

Comment: Do you know the definition of "specific volume."  If so, do you know the specific volume of liquid water and water vapor at the temperature and pressure?

Comment: @ChetMiller understand now, sorry for the delay. No, the water vapour isn't saturated in the initial condition

Comment: Then what is its temperature and pressure?

Comment: @ChetMiller sorry once again, $T_0=400K$ and $P_0=1 bar$

Comment: With these values of To and Po, the water vapor is superheated, and obeys the ideal gas law.  So you can determine the initial mass of vapor.  When you increase the pressure, it will remain superheated until you reach the saturation pressure at 127 C[ then you will begin forming liquid water>. The fraction liquid and vapor will depend on the total volume ,, and the specific volumes of liquid water and water vapor at 127 C.

Comment: @ChetMiller sure but how can we find the masses of the weights?

Comment: If $v_L$ is the specific volume of liquid water and $v_V$ is the specific volume of water vapor,, then $$m(1-x)v_L+mxv_V=V$$where x is the mass fraction vapor, m is the total mass of water in the cylinder, and V is the volume of the cylinder.